# metaball-like character animation

Tags: animation, game-physics

Does anybody know -or has some ideas- how the main character in the flash videogame [Huje Adventure](http://www.physicsgames.net/game/Huje_Adventure.html) is animated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found the answer, [blob/jelly physics](http://cowboyprogramming.com/2007/01/05/blob-physics/)